# How to Terminate Multiprocessing pool once the desired execution is completed

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm new to understanding multiprocessing pool. Here is a function which I want to be run and try to find a match of a desired hash. I want the pool to be terminated as soon as the result is found, as other processes may still be running, which is not needed now.

```
def test(selector, bounds):
k = keccak.new(digest_bits=256)
k.update(bytes(selector, 'utf-8'))
selectorSig = k.hexdigest()[:8]
for i in range(bounds[0], bounds[1]):
    str = selector.split('(')[0] + f'_{i}(' + selector.split('(')[1]
    k = keccak.new(digest_bits=256)
    k.update(bytes(str, 'utf-8'))
    if k.hexdigest()[:8] == 'ae026468':
        return click.echo(f'Found collision with {str}')
        => This is where I want the pool to be terminated and close any other parallely running process <=
        break

# Below is the pseudocode where I'm creating a pool 

def callTest():
   ...
   a_pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
   a_pool.starmap(test, iters)
   a_pool.close()
   a_pool.join()
```

and please suggest any optimization that can be made regarding the pools

Comment: The pool should be joining them as they return. It should be checking here if it gets a positive result, so that it can cancel / close / shutdown the rest of them or prevent new ones from starting

Comment: Hey @AnthonyL can you provide a code sample to understand it better. I tried using starmap_async to get the callbacks from function test(return True if hash matches) into `results` and calling `a_pool.terminate()` if the result is true (from the results.get()). However, it seems like the remaining processes are still executing their tasks

Comment: I would use [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) It's the same thing; just a higher level, and the link shows an example that is more useable

Comment: @RazorSharp you can also pass a shared boolean flag using `multiprocessing.Value`. Check whether the flag is true regularly in your worker function. If it becomes false, break the loop and return. So, you set the flag to false when you get the value in the worker function and all other workers will then quit